# What is the Armv8 VMMU address range limit for 4K pages

Tags: paging, mmu, armv8

We need to be able to address something that is fixed at address 0x200-0000-0000 on an ARMv8 system that uses a hypervisor with VMMU that is configured with 4K page sizes.  It appears to me that it is impossible to reach that address unless I switch to a 64K page size which will have bad implications elsewhere.  Here is is the math - tell me if I am wrong somehow:

The root table has 512 entries and each one addresses up to a 0x4000-0000 range.  512 x 0x4000-0000 is 0x80-0000-0000 which falls short of the address that I need to reach.  If someone knows a workaround without switching to 64K pages, I would like to know it.  (The problem with 64K pages is that it is too broad to include and exclude memory and devices in a granular way, so we would like to avoid it).

Answer (score 0):

MMU is not flat, it's multilevel hierarchical being...

So each level has 512 entries. When you set page size 4KB, that means lowest level consisting of 512 entries has physical addresses on 4KB pages.

Next upper level operates in `512 * 4KB = 2MB` mappings. Respectively every entry (out of 512 entries in total) on this level could either map 2MB directly or point to list of `512 * 4KB` entries.

And so on, eg next upper level is `512 * 2MB = 1GB` with same functionality, either mapping a whole 1GB or pointing on lower level of `512 * 2MB`.

Yes you could go even higher! But to reach desired `0x200-0000-0000`, entries on 1GB level is good enough.

All you need now is to set translation configuration. In AArch64 it's `TCR_EL1, Translation Control Register (EL1)` register.
Particularly you need `T1SZ, bits [21:16]` and `T0SZ, bits [5:0]` fields.

For 512GB max memory size (eg 512 mmu entries by 1GB) field value should be `25`.

Comment: I believe 3 levels is the limit. So the third level, 1GB * 512 = 0x80-0000-0000 which is not high enough to reach 0x200-0000-0000.  That was the essence of my question.

Comment: Sorry, miscounted number of zeroes in question. But AArch64 has up to 4 levels, allowing addresses of up to 48 bits. 3 levels is about AArch32.

Comment: From reference manual "The VMSAv8-64 translation table format" section: `The VMSAv8-64 translation table format provides:
• Up to four levels of address lookup.
• Input addresses of up to 48 bits.
• Output addresses of up to 48 bits.
• A translation granule size of 4KB, 16KB, or 64KB.`